# Youtube login authentication failed

Tags: authentication, youtube

When I do youtube login authentication, the code is as follows:

---

'GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                clientID:kMyClientID
                                                            clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
                                                        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];'
```

Authentication failed after running. But when I set clientSecret to nil when the certification has been successful, why?

Comment: Which programing language did you use

Comment: Thanks,I use Object-c.